# How to change the display of my field?

Tags: entities

I have a field in one of my content types called lab_test_id. When Editors add content of that type they enter all the ids of the lab tests associated with that node. I need to be able to take that id, call that lab test database, and display the lab test fields I get back.

Can I accomplish that by changing the display of the lab_test_id field via hook_field_display_alter or should I find another way to accomplish that?

Comment: "call that lab test database, and display the lab test fields I get back." - are "lab tests" drupal content, or is that completely separate custom database outside drupal?

Comment: It is a completely separate custom database

Comment: Drupal works easier if the content is located within its own database. If you would have 'lab tests' as a content type, it would as easy as to work with Entity reference and Display Suite :-) You 'could' duplicate the data to Drupal first with Feeds or something if that is an approach you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using [`hook_field_display_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7), however, I would personally prefer to create a custom formatter for the used field type. With the main advantage that you can save settings for the field formatter.

See the answers of [How do I write an additional field formatter for an existing field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79556/how-do-i-write-an-additional-field-formatter-for-an-existing-field) for basic steps on how to create your own field formatter.

Comment: Going to your link I found a nice little module called Custom Formatters which might do the trick too.
It does the same thing just is set up so that you don't have to set up a custom module.

Comment: Interesting module, didn't know about that one yet :)